# Load torque and Rotor torque

Tags: motor, torque

What would happen if the load torque became greater than the rotor torque developed by the motor?

Comment: Any time the motor torque and load torque are not equal, the rotor will accelerate or decelerate, and it will keep doing that until the torques are equal.

Comment: If the load torque is greater than motor torque, and in the opposing direction, then the motor will decelerate. Depending on the motor type and controller (if any) the torque may increase as the motor slows down, until a new equilibrium is found. Otherwise, it will stall.

Answer (score 2):

If the load torque is great than the rotor torque three things **could** occur. First thing to appreciate is the torque production at lower velocities is generally higher than at higher velocities.

Consider one of the fundamental equations of an electrical machine \$T = J \dot\omega\$.  Torque is equal to the system inertia multiplied by the angular acceleration. With J being constant for a given system...

A positive torque (\$T_{rotor} - T_{load}\$ > 0) will result in positive acceleration.

A negative torque (\$T_{rotor} - T_{load}\$ < 0) will result in negative acceleration.

**NOTE**: Positive in this instance indicate commanded rotation which could be clockwise or counter-clockwise

So... assuming the system is rotating at a given velocity and the load torque is increased to that greater than the electrical machines capability:

1) the rotor will slow down. This is guaranteed to happen.

Now depending on the torque-velocity characteristics of the motor, the system may just settle at a lower velocity. If however the torque still exceeds the machines capability and thus the rotor continues to decelerate

2) The rotor will stall.

Depending on the source of the load, if the load torque is still in excess of the electrical machine torque...

3) Rotor will accelerate

The rotor will now begin to accelerate in the opposite direction to the commanded direction because it is overwhelmed by the load.